# Android: Simulate WiFi in the emulator?

Tags: android, testing, android-emulator, wifi, device-emulation

I would like to check from my app whether the device has WiFi connectivity, but in order to do that, I must first find a way to get "WiFi" in the emulator. Just going to **Settings -> Wireless controls -> Wifi** says *Unable to start Wi-Fi*, while `logcat` says:

```
E/WifiService(  566): Failed to load Wi-Fi driver.
D/SettingsWifiEnabler(  695): Received wifi state changed from Unknown to Enabling
D/SettingsWifiEnabler(  695): Received wifi state changed from Enabling to Unknown
```

How can I simulate WiFi connectivity in the emulator?

Comment: so how could u deal with this? have u solved it out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since this seems to be a popular question, I'll go ahead and add an updated answer. The SDK still doesn't support WiFi emulation, but [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) does WiFi by default, so you can use that to develop/test apps with specific WiFi functionality.

Comment: Correct, but only in the licensed version atm.

Comment: 2017 update, it's now available in the [API 25 emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator.html#26-1-3) when you disable hardware acceleration -

Answer (score 20):

Currently, while you can use your computer's Internet connection in the emulator, it's not reliable to use it for simulating Wi-Fi. The [`WifiManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) gets confused when you switch/want to test your connectivity state.

Even in Android 1.5, there were some problems with it ([Issue 2571 - android](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2571)), and while you can use your Internet for simulating HTTP connections and downloading data, finer control over Wi-Fi connectivity should better be done with a device.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Android emulator wifi]

Starting from revision 26.1.3, the Android emulator now supports connecting to WiFi on a Nougat image (API 25).

> Added support for Wi-Fi in some system images (currently only API level 25). An access point called "AndroidWifi" is available and Android automatically connects to it.

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator.html#26-1-3

You can check the version of your emulator by going into emulator settings (three dots) > Help > About. Also note that if an AVD was created before version 26.1.3 was released, you will have to recreate your AVD. I read somewhere that wiping data might also work, but I did not try that.

Comment: I needed to disable hardware acceleration for it to be available. At time of writing set `Emulated Performance Graphics` to `Software - GLES 2.0`.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have a real device, I think the best way is installing [android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) or use it on live usb. There is no diffrences between android and android-x86.

And android-x86 support wi-fi. so you can install your app, and run it.

Comment: alright... but does it work as it is ? I mean simulating wifi from that emulator (virtualbox) ? :D

Comment: As of today, it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

In theory, linux (the kernel underlying android) has [mac80211_hwsim](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/mac80211_hwsim) driver, which simulates WiFi. It can be used to set up several WiFi devices (an acces point, and another WiFi device, and so on), which would make up a WiFi network.

It's useful for testing WiFi programs under linux. Possibly, even under [user-mode linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-mode_Linux) or other isolated virtual "boxes" with linux.

In theory, this driver could be used for tests in the android systems where you don't have a real WiFi device (or don't want to use it), and also in some kind of android emulators. Perhaps, one can manage to use this driver in android-x86, or--for testing--in android-x86 run in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2):

Probably no substitute for testing on a real device, but if you're looking for a good enough test case in the emulator give [Fake Wifi Connection](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-fake-wifi-connection-t2800416) a try:

It makes apps think they're on wifi no matter what the underlying connection is.

**disclaimer:** I wrote this stuff.
It works by intercepting ConnectivityManager / WifiManager calls (uses [Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)). I've tried to cover most of them so it does a pretty good job, nevertheless it's always possible some is missing (if you find something let me know).