# Simulate Wireless Network in Emulator

Tags: android

How do I simulate a WiFi network using the Emulator?

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: you can't. Also, this [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563370/android-simulate-wifi-in-the-emulator) (and yes, it's still valid).

Answer (score 1):

The emulator does not emulate WiFi specifically. It emulates a generic network connection. You can use [telnet commands](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#netstatus) to configure its characteristics (e.g., speed, latency).

Comment: You have more rep than me. Can you please edit the question and fix the title? The "Imulator" makes me cringe :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with for simulating total network connection loss on the emulator:

Write the following script and name it "nonetwork.sh"

```
netcfg eth0 down
sleep 10
netcfg eth0 up
netcfg eth0 dhcp
```

Upload the following script to the emulator via this command:

```
adb push nonetwork.sh /data/local/nonetwork.sh
```

Change the permissions

```
adb shell chmod 700 /data/local/nonetwork.sh
```

Run it

```
adb shell /data/local/nonetwork.sh
```

While the network is down on the device you'll lose access to adb as well but once the connection is re-established it will work again. Hope this helps.

Comment: What does this have to do with simulating WiFi?