# Android Emulator - Wifi Error

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-wifi

I am using the Android SDK Emulator ad trying to connect to the web. I can not do it as in the settings > Wireless & Networks , Where i need to turn the WiFi On, i get "Error"

How to solve it?

Gorov

Comment: I have the same problem, did you fix it? @_@

Comment: does someone fix this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27463792/566092 - Switching to genymotion worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

1. Shut down the emulator.
2. Turn off Ethernet, Firewire, and any other network interfaces. All of them. And I mean completely shut them off, e.g. on a Mac, open System Preferences > Network > Ethernet > Configure > OFF. Simply unplugging the Ethernet cable is not enough.
3. Enable Wifi and verify it works.
4. Launch the Android emulator.

It should now display a 3G icon (or similar) in the status bar, and you should be now able to surf the web.

Comment: FWIW this helped me overcome "no ethernet/wifi connection detected" which was causing WebView html5 video to "just not load at all" FWIW

Comment: seriously strange how this works.  here have some stackoverflow points.

Answer (score 5):

Look at [Controlling the Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#controlling).

Press F8 in the emulator, this should enable your data connection. It's weird, sometimes the connection is disabled when you start up the Emulator.

Regards

Comment: I did what you suggested and it is still not working and there is still an error

Comment: F8 does NOT turn on the wifi.

Answer (score 3):

I think, sometimes emulator wont connect to internet if you start the emulator after connecting your internet connection to the computer... try connecting the internet first and then starting the emulator....

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [Enabling Wifi on Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876302/enabling-wifi-on-android-emulator) and [Android: Simulate WiFi in the emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563370/android-simulate-wifi-in-the-emulator), this simply isn't supported in the emulator. If you want wifi, you need a real device.

As other people in this question have stated, you can access the internet in general: whether your computer is using a wired or wireless network, it's possible to configure your emulator's "3G" or "4G" to pull the network from the host machine. But the emulator-internal "WiFi" can't work correctly.

(this question is probably a duplicate. Even the later of the two questions I referenced is almost a duplicate of the other)

Comment: No longer true: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#wi-fi

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to "turn on" the wifi of the AVD. It should work using your computers internet connection. Here is what worked for me when wifi on my AVD stops working(I needed to reset my AVD):

- Close AVD and confirm it is not running
- Open AVD Manager in Android Studio (Tools > AVD Manager)
- Click on the dropdown arrow on the right side of the emulator
- Click "Wipe Data"
- Confirm the internet on your computer is working then re-launch AVD

This issue recurs for me sometimes but after I complete the above steps it works again.

Answer (score 3):

Below solution worked in most of the cases.

close emulator->Switch off laptop wifi -> open **AVD Manager** in android studio-> Perform **cold reboot** of required emulator ->After emulator reboot completely,switch on laptop wifi

After above steps,it works.Please find below image for emulator cold boot

[image]

Comment: This one works. Basically i slept my laptop over night and open it in morning, seems messed up with dns somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I made a factory reset in VS in manage android devices and after that emulator was connected to wifi!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21193154)

Comment: Yes but this, solved the wifi problem. Maybe it is a good workaround.

Comment: This worked for me too and saved me some effort.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57559459/276383 below if you need it more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this problem when I was using Win7.
I had to switch to a wired connection as nothing seemed to be working.

F8 is indeed the key to turn network on/off, but it just didn't work for me.

I later switched to Ubuntu, but didn't test whether emulator works with wifi on Ubuntu.

Comment: I did what you suggested and it is still not working and there is still an error

Comment: What? You switched to a wired connection?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to unplug my ethernet lan cable and enable my Wi-FI connection. Seems it was mixing both.

My computer uses MAC and I was working with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can't switch the Wi-Fi ON in the emulator. This is a particularly tricky issue when working behind a firewall or a proxy.

In some cases, however, using only ONE of ethernet or Wi-Fi might help.

But you can connect to the internet through the emulator if you can configure the APNs properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another possible cause: Check the DNS settings on your computer.

Turns out I still had the DNS server from my work set in the computers WiFi properties (**not** the Emulator WiFi settings). Everything has been working fine for a week, including the emulator until today. Only the emulator stopped working, everything else was still able to connect. Wiping data, cold booting and restarting the laptop didn't help.

Removing all DNS servers from the WiFi properties, wiping data and doing a cold boot finally made it work again. You might wanna do a DHCP renew as well.