# executing WIFIDirectDemo sample with multiple android emulators

Tags: android

I want to try the sample Wifi Direct Demo

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/index.html on multiple android emulators, but I'm not able to activate the Wifi P2P on each emulator. Is it possible to do so?

PS: I took a look about the port forwarding, but it doesn't work since a Wifi connection is needed before.

Comment: This is a real issue with developing wifi direct applications. But unfortunately I've found no way to do it.

Comment: You can try this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770774/getting-started-with-open-nfc-emulator

Answer (score 1):

I had experienced the same problem lately and crawled the web regarding that. I am afraid the only way to try the demo out is to run the app on an actual device. Android emulator can not reach or change wi-fi configurations. Here are some links:

[Android: Simulate WiFi in the emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563370/android-simulate-wifi-in-the-emulator)

[Enabling Wifi on Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876302/enabling-wifi-on-android-emulator)

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c879564f43eb12e4/c610b7c37157ffe7%3Fq%3D%2522Bradley%2BKite%2522%23c610b7c37157ffe7&ei=iGwTS6eaOpW8Qpmqic0O&sa=t&ct=res&cd=2&source=groups&usg=AFQjCNHfdUuFFu7aRhcHRC3x6I9Y6vBzzw