# Wi-Fi Direct technology

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-direct

I'm thinking about create an app that transfers video streaming via Wi-Fi Direct.  I've already googled (even in Stackoverflow) that, but I haven't found a list specifying the supported devices.

My question is: **Is it possible to code an application using Wi-Fi Direct on Samsung Galaxy Mini (GT-S5570B with Android 2.3.6 Gingerbread)? Is there a hardware limitation about this technology or just the code is enough?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Android platform, devices with Android 2.3 or Gingerbread and below support WiFi Direct **only if the manufacturer decides to add on the feature and with some code modification over the Android** operating system (OS) **(So, if you see WiFi direct in the Settings App of your android OS then, yes you have wifi direct and you can develop applications)**. The **LG Optimus Black, Samsung Galaxy S and Galaxy S II, Galaxy S III** are examples of existing smartphones in the market that support WiFi Direct. Some Sony BRAVIA LED TVs with WiFi Direct allow media sharing via Sony Ericsson Xperia smartphones.

Google later added the WiFi Direct support in their latest Android 4.0 or Ice Cream Sandwich OS. This makes the Samsung Galaxy Nexus the first Android phone that offers native WiFi Direct without any tethering from the manufacturer.

I suggest to look at [this.](http://www.mobile88.com/news/read.asp?file=/2012/1/6/20120106140457&phone=wifi-direct-demystified)

**EDIT:** For Emulator also I don't see any settings for WI-FI Direct. I don't think you can test that on emulator. Please look at this links,

[executing WIFIDirectDemo sample with multiple android emulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640565/executing-wifidirectdemo-sample-with-multiple-android-emulators)

Comment: This complicated my life, because I really need to develop an application using Wi-Fi Direct and I won't have a smartphone to test immediately. Does the Android emulator (on Eclipse) can help me get an ideia of operation?

Answer (score 2):

You can get information about which Sony Xperia devices support Wi-Fi Direct from the [Wi-Fi Alliance website](http://certifications.wi-fi.org/search_products.php?search=1&advanced=1&lang=en&filter_company_id=756&filter_category_id=&filter_subcategory=&filter_cid=&date_from=&date_to=&selected_certifications%5B%5D=50&x=67&y=24).
Sony also has a [phone loaner program](http://developer.sonymobile.com/services/borrow-a-phone/) in which you can apply for borrowing of a device.