# Get MAC Address Android Crashes APP

Tags: android

I'm trying to get MAC addres of Wifi network of Eclipse android emulator with this:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) LoginActivity.this.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress(); 
            System.out.println("HI");
            System.out.println(macAddress);
```

This is the android manifest permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

When the execution arrives to

```
System.out.println(macAddress);
```

The app crashes  with java nullpointerexception and close it.

What are doing wrong? I have to add wifi conectivity to emulator?

Comment: you can not use wify connection with emulator [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876302/enabling-wifi-on-android-emulator)

Answer (score 2):

The doc about [`WifiManager.getConnectionInfo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConnectionInfo%28%29) states that it :

> Return dynamic information about the current Wi-Fi connection, if any
>   is active.

This means that in this case, you'd want to check whether your `WifiInfo` is not `null` and that your device is effectively connected to a Wi-Fi network. In the case of the emulator, the MAC address is always `null`, so you should make sure what you're outputting is valid.