# No internet access on emulator using API level 25 with an Android wifi

Tags: android-emulator

Working on vm which is connected to internet using either net and using proxy. Android studio version is 2.3.3 and I am using httpProxy in this but when Trying to open AVD from AVD manager it will open and connected to "android wifi" but with no internet access.
I have tried to launch AVD from command prompt using option -dns - server but won't work for me. Please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling WiFi on Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876302/enabling-wifi-on-android-emulator)

Comment: Not get anything productive from the post.. No solution provided

Comment: Which version are you using on emulator? You may need to update emulator version.

Comment: Do you mean Android studio or emulator

Comment: I mean emulator version. WiFi support is added on emulator version 26.1.3.