# Connecting an Emulated Android Device to a Virtual Machine as a USB device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb, vmware

I want to run an executable which interacts with an emulated device by executing adb commands and performing other actions. However, since the program is untrustworthy, I want to run it on a virtual machine. I already have an Android Studio emulator on my host machine, and I would prefer not to download and run another instance of Android Studio on the guest machine (unnecessary duplication).

I have learned that I can enable adb over wifi, which theoretically should allow me to accomplish my goal. However, the emulator I want to use is running Android 6, and I read on StackOverflow ([Enabling WiFi on Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876302/enabling-wifi-on-android-emulator)) that wifi is not available on emulators running API levels below 25 (such as Android 6).

Is there a way for me to still accomplish my task? Perhaps there is a way to connect the emulated device to the VMware Workstation virtual machine as if it were connected with a physical USB device?

Thank you

Comment: You can simply forward the adb port from within the virtual machine to your host machine. How to do so can be found multiple times here on SO, especially in combination with WSL, so you just have to adapt these answers to VMWare.