# No WiFi on the Android Emulator: is it a lack in the AOSP code or in the driver part?

Tags: android-emulator, android-wifi

The final goal is to enable the WiFi in the Android Emulator (like [Genmotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)), but before starting big project, I want to know in which part I need to take a look.

Does the WiFi disabled in the AOSP code or in the driver part of the Android Emulator?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563370/android-simulate-wifi-in-the-emulator

Comment: Yeap, I have made research before, but the question is: is the wifi disabled in the img file or is it a lack of the emulator itself ?